# Using `UIButton.Configuration` in a `UICollectionViewCell` breaks the label placement when rotating

Tags: ios, swift

When using a `UIButton`, with a `UIButton.Configuration` to set its title and image, inside a `UICollectionViewCell` the button itself breaks the image/label positioning when rotating.

This is what it looks like initially:

[image: initial]

Then after rotating once

[image: rotated once]

And then when rotating back

[image: rotating back]

Code:

```
import UIKit

final class ViewController: UIViewController {
    private let cellRegistration = UICollectionView.CellRegistration<ButtonCollectionViewCell, String> { _, _, _ in }

    private lazy var dataSource = UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource<String, String>(
        collectionView: collectionView,
        cellProvider: { collectionView, indexPath, identifier in
            collectionView.dequeueConfiguredReusableCell(
                using: self.cellRegistration,
                for: indexPath,
                item: ""
            )
        }
    )

    private lazy var collectionView: UICollectionView = {
        let collectionViewLayout = UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout { _, _ in
            let layoutSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(
                widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1.0),
                heightDimension: .estimated(30)
            )

            let group = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(
                layoutSize: layoutSize,
                subitems: [
                    NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: layoutSize)
                ]
            )

            let layout = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: group)
            layout.contentInsetsReference = .safeArea
            layout.contentInsets = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: 24, leading: 12, bottom: 0, trailing: 12)
            return layout
        }

        return UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: collectionViewLayout)
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var snapshot = NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshot<String, String>()
        snapshot.appendSections(["section"])
        snapshot.appendItems(["item"], toSection: "section")
        
        dataSource.apply(snapshot)

        view.addSubview(collectionView)
    }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

        collectionView.frame = view.bounds
    }
}

final class ButtonView: UIView {
    private lazy var button: UIButton = {
        let image = UIImage(systemName: "headphones")!
            .withTintColor(.white)
            .withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)

        let title = AttributedString(NSAttributedString(string: "Listen", attributes: [
            .foregroundColor: UIColor.white
        ]))

        var configuration = UIButton.Configuration.plain()
        configuration.attributedTitle = title
        configuration.image = image
        configuration.titleAlignment = .center
        configuration.imagePadding = 4
        configuration.background.backgroundColor = .blue
        configuration.background.cornerRadius = 8

        return UIButton(configuration: configuration)
    }()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        addSubview(button)
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        button.frame = bounds
    }

    override func sizeThatFits(_ size: CGSize) -> CGSize {
        button.sizeThatFits(size)
    }
}

final class ButtonCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    private let buttonView = ButtonView()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        contentView.addSubview(buttonView)
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        buttonView.frame = contentView.bounds
    }

    override func sizeThatFits(_ size: CGSize) -> CGSize {
        buttonView.sizeThatFits(size)
    }
}
```

The view inspector doesn't yield anything useful either

[image: view inspector]

The only thing I've found that helps is setting the `autoresizingMask` of the `UIButton` *and* its container view, which a) make no sense at all b) doesn't work outside this sample app to reproduce it (e.g. the solution is not completely reliable)

Also using the "old" APIs, `setTitle("Title", for: .normal)` / `setImage(image, for: .normal)` does not cause this bug.

Anyone seen this before and have any clue what could possible be wrong here?

Comment: Isn't it just the matter of applying constraints to the button?

Comment: @ElTomato no? There's no constraint usage here, this is manual layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could avoid that issue completely by using auto-layout / constraints.

However, if you have some valid reason NOT to do so...

In your `ButtonView` class, change `layoutSubviews` to this:

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    
    if button.frame != bounds {
        button.frame = bounds
        button.setNeedsLayout()
        button.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}
```

Comment: `UIButton.Configuration` being broken in a non auto-layout context is a pretty nasty bug on Apple's end. Interesting workaround though, doesn't seem suuuuper safe.

Comment: @ClausJørgensen - yeah, I'd consider it a "bug" worth reporting. Since it is a bit unusual these days to set frames instead of letting auto-layout handle things, I might guess that was missed by Apple devs. However, I don't think this workaround would be "un-safe" ... there are a number of cases where we need to explicitly tell auto-layout to update UI elements in a similar fashion.